# How to fix '0' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file?

Tags: environment-variables, command-prompt

Whenever I run cmd the line '0' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file " is always show-up. Thanks before
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvU1a.jpg)

Comment: How do you open the command prompt window? Is it via the _Start_ button?

Comment: Yes. I open it via Start button

Comment: Do you enter `cmd.exe` in the search box, or do you click on the icon in the start menu?

Comment: Click the icon in the start menu

Comment: Right click the icon and select _properties_ from the context menu. Under the _shortcut_ tab, look what's written in the _target_ text field. That is the command that is invoked when you click on the icon. Alternatively, rather than click on the icon, simply enter `cmd` in the search box.

Comment: In target section it says: %windir%\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: Check `reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun` and `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun`

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem earlier, I managed to fix it in the Registry Editor.

see: [screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H02H.png)

**This is what I did:**

1. open REGEDIT
2. Locate the cmd registry:

```
        Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

[screenshot of the REGEDIT for CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3lcC.png)

- In my case I had a datavalue of `Autorun` that was set to `0`

3. Find the suspect stringvalue: " `Autorun` "
4. Rightclick on the stringvalue, and choose **Modify...**
5. Change the "*Value data:*" to "nothing" [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEj3l.png)
6. If that doesn't solve the "annoying message", delete the `Autorun`-variable

- Right click on the variable and hit delete

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

call c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
pause

Comment: Not likely to help... Where would you run that, and why do you think it will remove the error message?

Comment: Hello there,

It is an attempt to open your cmd and see if your error goes away.
Open a notepad, paste: 

call c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe

pause

Save the file in your desktop with the extension .bat
Double click in your file and see if it is still there.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it